# Find the operator norm of T with $Tf(x)=f(ax) + f(x/a)$ in $L^2(0, \infty)$ with a > 1.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I just found, applying the definition, $\|T\| \leq 1/a + a$

wich i think is true but how do i find $\|T\|$?

Comment: I think you should maybe state the whole question you’re asking

Comment: @DominicPetti My question is: how do i find ||T||? where T is defined in the title...

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac 1 {|x|^{\frac 1 4}}$ for $|x|<1$, then $x\mapsto f(\frac 1 x)$ is not in $L^2$. So $f\in L^2$ but $Tf\notin L^2$. What norm are you considering for $Tf$?

Comment: @StefanLafon Im sorry, fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you fixed. I believe my example still holds, that is $Tf\notin L^2(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @StefanLafon ok, this must do the job...

Comment: Now that looks better :)